# Positive integer to Roman Numeral conversion function

Tags: converting, vb.net, roman-numerals

For the past two hours I was searching for a built-in function for converting an integer to an equivalent Roman numeral, but it failed to achieve  the target. Hence I wrote my own routine for performing this conversion. I think it needs some more clarifications.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ind() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000}
    Dim rom() As String = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"}
    Dim limit As Integer = 9
    Dim output As String = ""
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim num As Integer
        output = ""
        num = CInt(txt1.Text)
        While num > 0
            num = find(num)
        End While
        txt2.Text = output
    End Sub
    Public Function find(ByVal Num As Integer) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While ind(i) <= Num
            i += 1
        End While
        If i <> 0 Then
            limit = i - 1
        Else
            limit = 0
        End If
        output = output & rom(limit)
        Num = Num - ind(limit)
        Return Num
    End Function
End Class
```

Note:  **This function can only be used for range of 1-999**

Comment: Does this help ? (Format numbers to roman numerals)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305822/format-numbers-to-roman-numerals

Comment: Why do you need clarification? This is just a reversed version of your own [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24879533/1842065). The code is almost identical. With that being said, it failed with an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at the first run. Try enter `1234`.

Comment: SoEnLion : defenitly work but need to extend. now the function is capable of provide answer below 1000.

Comment: The code functions as advertised from 1-999. I can review this. Please leave it open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- This code is bound far too tight to your form. The first thing we need to do is separate the logic for converting an integer to a roman numeral from the event procedures of the form. This will allow us to reuse this code *anywhere*.

  ```
  Module IntegerExtensions

      Dim ind() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000}
      Dim rom() As String = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"}
      Dim limit As Integer = 9
      Dim output As String = ""

      Private Function ConvertToRomanNumeral(ByVal input As Integer) As String
          output = ""
          While input > 0
              input = find(input)
          End While
          Return output
      End Function

      Private Function Find(ByVal Num As Integer) As Integer
          Dim i As Integer = 0
          While ind(i) <= Num
              i += 1
          End While
          If i <> 0 Then
              limit = i - 1
          Else
              limit = 0
          End If
          output = output & rom(limit)
          Num = Num - ind(limit)
          Return Num
      End Function

  End Module

  Public Class Form1
      Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

          txt2.Text = IntegerExtensions.ConvertToRomanNumeral(999)        

      End Sub
  End Class
  ```
- Next we need to make sure that the argument passed to `ConvertToRomanNumeral` is within the accepted range of 1-999. Receiving a `Index out of bounds` message is not nearly as useful as knowing that `ConvertToRomanNumeral` doesn't accept the value you passed into it.

  ```
  Private Function ConvertToRomanNumeral(ByVal input As Integer) As String

      If (input < 1 Or input > 999) Then
          Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input","Input must be in the range 1-999")
      End If

      output = ""
      While input > 0
          input = find(input)
      End While
      Return output
  End Function
  ```
- `ind` and `rom` are not very good variable names. I get that `rom` stands for Roman Numerals, but I have no idea what `ind` means. Indices maybe? Also, I like plural names for arrays. Let's replace those. `ind` >> `indices` and `rom` >> `romanNumerals`.
- There are way too many class level variables. `Limit` should be strictly declared inside of `Find`. I also don't find it a good idea to set the value of `output` from the `Find` function. I would consider this to be a side effect, and side effects are confusing and hard to debug. The only way for me to properly scope `output` was to merge `Find` into `ConvertToRomanNumeral`.

  ```
  Module IntegerExtensions

      Private Function ConvertToRomanNumeral(ByVal input As Integer) As String

          If (input < 1 Or input > 999) Then
              Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input","Input must be in the range 1-999")
          End If

          Dim indices() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000}
          Dim romanNumerals() As String = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"}
          Dim limit As Integer = 9
          Dim output As String = ""

          While input > 0
              Dim number as Integer = input
              Dim i As Integer = 0
              While indices(i) <= number
                  i += 1
              End While
              If i <> 0 Then
                  limit = i - 1
              Else
                  limit = 0
              End If
              output = output & romanNumerals(limit)
              number = number - indices(limit)
              ' this was previously our return statement
              input = number                  
          End While
          Return output
      End Function

  End Module
  ```
- You may have noticed earlier that I named the module `IntegerExtensions`. That's because I've been planning on making this exactly that the entire time. [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) will allow us to call the function directly on any integer, instead of passing an integer into it. It looks a little cleaner when in use. I changed the function name to `ToRomanNumberal` and adjusted the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` message accordingly.

  ```
  Module IntegerExtensions

      <Extension()>
      Public Function ToRomanNumeral(ByVal input As Integer) As String

          If (input < 1 Or input > 999) Then
              Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input","Cannot convert integers outside of the range 1-999")
          End If

          Dim indices() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000}
          Dim romanNumerals() As String = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"}
          Dim limit As Integer = 9
          Dim output As String = ""

          While input > 0
              Dim number as Integer = input
              Dim i As Integer = 0
              While indices(i) <= number
                  i += 1
              End While
              If i <> 0 Then
                  limit = i - 1
              Else
                  limit = 0
              End If
              output = output & romanNumerals(limit)
              number = number - indices(limit)
              ' this was previously our return statement
              input = number                  
          End While
          Return output
      End Function

  End Module
  ```

**Excercises for you:**

- How could this be done using a [dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet) instead.
- How can this be changed so that numbers outside of 1-999 can be converted?

Comment: I would just like to note that there is still a fair bit of improvement that can be made. I was just getting a bit tired.

Answer (score 6):

To catch up where [ckuhn203](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243/ckuhn203) got tired, I would like to finish `ckuhn203`'s review.

- Validating the input

  As it is senseless to check wether `input > 999` in the case that `input < 1` we can use the short-circuiting boolean operator [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx)

  ```
  If (input < 1 OrElse input > 999) Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input","Cannot convert integers outside of the range 1-999")
  End If
  ```
- Initializing String variables

  For readability you should initialize String variables by assigning [String.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

  ```
  Dim output As String = ""
  ```

  will become

  ```
  Dim output As String = String.Empty
  ```
- Inside the while loop

  This

  ```
  If i <> 0 Then
      limit = i - 1
  Else
      limit = 0
  End If
  ```

  is logically wrong. What would happen if `i=-1` ? As it is `<>0` `limit` would become `-2`. So it needs to be changed to

  ```
  If i > 0 Then
      limit = i - 1
  Else
      limit = 0
  End If
  ```

  next we get rid of the `number` variable as it isn't needed

  ```
  While input > 0

      Dim i As Integer = 0
      While indices(i) <= input
          i += 1
      End While
      If i > 0 Then
          limit = i - 1
      Else
          limit = 0
      End If
      output = output & romanNumerals(limit)
      input = input - indices(limit)

  End While
  ```

  And because we have the validation of the input number, I don't see a reason to keep the `limit` variable at all, so let us remove it

  ```
  While input > 0

      Dim i As Integer = 0
      While indices(i) <= input
          i += 1
      End While
      If i > 0 Then
          i -= 1
      Else
          i = 0
      End If
      output = output & romanNumerals(i)
      input = input - indices(i)

  End While
  ```

  and because `i < 0` can't happen, we simplify the `if i > 0` by removing the `else` part and get the result

  ```
  <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
  Public Function ToRomanNumeral(ByVal input As Integer) As String

      If (input < 1 OrElse input > 999) Then
          Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input", "Cannot convert integers outside of the range 1-999")
      End If

      Dim indices() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000}
      Dim romanNumerals() As String = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"}
      Dim output As String = String.Empty

      While input > 0

          Dim i As Integer = 0
          While indices(i) <= input
              i += 1
          End While
          If i > 0 Then
              i -= 1
          End If
          output = output & romanNumerals(i)
          input = input - indices(i)

      End While

      Return output
  End Function
  ```